# NSManagedObjects with Categories

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, categories, nsmanagedobject

I believe it is a common practice to put custom code for a `NSManagedObject` in a category of the subclass since Xcode will overrite your generated subclass when the model is edited.  I just wanted to confirm this.  I have seen examples where people say it is bad to combine categories with methods that are already implemented in the class hierarchy.  I'm not sure if this is just for the cases when the class that has the actual category has the method already implemented or in all cases.

Comment: I've struggled with this question for a long time and finally went with a solution that modified the object hierarchy.  You can read about it here if you're interested: http://bikepress.org/?p=1120.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with overriding a method in a category is that you can't call the original implementation like you'd normally do using `[super doSomething]`. Usually, when you override a method, you still want to be able to call the original implementation doing something extra before and/or after the original implementation gets executed.

One fairly clean solution is to let Xcode generate NSManagedObject subclasses that you don't touch directly. Instead, create another, custom subclass of each Xcode-generated NSManagedObject subclass that you can edit without worrying about it being overwritten.

Wolf Rentzsch's [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/) essentially uses this approach, and additionally generates some nice convenience methods that Xcode doesn't generate. Might be worth checking out because it can be a helpful tool, but mogenerator is not necessary to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: When using the subclass of the auto-generated NSManagedObject subclass - how do I deal with relationships?  Object A has an Object  B and wants to call method doSomething but doSomething is defined in my subclass of B but Core Data did not return my subclass of B - it actually returns B.  Do you know where I can find an example of this?

Comment: @Brian I know this is a late answer to your question. But here is how you can fix it. Make the auto-generated NSManagedObject subclass free of properties. It contains only custom methods (that means you can make it abstract too). Then class A can subclass this class and has its own properties. Same goes for class B. When you call a method of class B it will work simply because class B inherits its method from another auto-generated NSManagedObject. In brief, the super class becomes an interface (or a protocol in Obj-c). And your subclasses are data storage + implementing this interface.

Comment: @Brian That of course reverses Andrew's answer. Because now the super class is getting untouchable (from Core Data point of view) and the subclass can change its data however you like.