# Custom init for a NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

How can I code a custom `init` for `NSManagedObject` subclass? I would like something like `initItemWithName:Volume:` for instance. Where `Item` is a `NSManagedObject` subclass with two attributes, `name` and `volume`.

Comment: Take a look at the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489578/custom-initializer-for-an-nsmanagedobject.
I'll help you out probably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Carlos,

As **Nenad Mihajlovic** suggested you could create a category for this.

So, for example, if you have an `Item` class, you could create a category called `Item+Management` and put the creation code there. Here you can find a simple example.

```
// .h

@interface Item (Management)

+ (Item*)itemWithName:(NSString *)theName volume:(NSNumber*)theVolume inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;

@end

// .m

+ (Item*)itemWithName:(NSString *)theName volume:(NSNumber*)theVolume inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    Item* item = (Item*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    theItem.name = theName;
    theItem.volume = theVolume;

    return item;
}
```

When you want to create a new Item, do an import like

```
#import "Item+Management.h"
```

and use like this

```
Item* item = [Item itemWithName:@"test" volume:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10] inManagedObjectContext:yourContext];
// do what you want with item...
```

This approach is very flexible and very easy to maintain during the app developing.

You can find further info at [Stanford Course Lecture 14](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2011-fall) code sample. In addition, see also free videos on iTunes by Stanford (if you have an Apple ID).

Hope that helps.

P.S. For the sake of simplicity, I suppose `name` is a `NSString` and `volume` is a `NSNumber`. For `volume` it could be better to use `NSDecimalNumber` type.

Comment: Thanks a lot Flex_Addicted!! But, one question: why have we to create these methods on a category and not in the `NSManagedObject` subclass? I have several classes and I would need at least 7 categories.

Comment: You can find info at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297101/nsmanagedobjects-with-categories and at http://blog.chrismiles.info/2011/06/organising-core-data-for-ios.html (I like very much tips in the latter). A simple explanation if you use Xcode to generate a custom class for your managed object: if you modify something in your entity, and then generate the class to accommodate those changes, Xcode will overwrite the code you've written in the original subclass.